# django eggs template Loader error

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to install `dajax`/`dajaxice` according to their documentation, which suggests that I uncomment the eggs template loader (third in tuple below below) in my `settings.py`.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

However, this makes my site stop working with an "IOError at /: sys.stdin access restricted by mod_wsgi" on my development machine.  When I look at where the error arises, it arises in python eggs that are unconnected to this project (I'm not using virtualenv which may be able to help) (or even django) and disappears when I comment out the line again.  (The template its looking for is easily found in the `TEMPLATES_DIR` when the eggs loader is commented out).

The traceback is:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://[redacted URL]/
Django Version: 1.2.5
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'registration',
 'dajaxice',
 'dajax',
 'south',
 '[redacted app name].study_registration',
 'profiles']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'audit_log.middleware.UserLoggingMiddleware')



Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/[redacted user name]/django/[redacted app name]/study_registration/views.py" in menu
  671.     template = loader.get_template('study_registration/menu.html')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  157.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  128.             loader = find_template_loader(loader_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/template/loader.py" in find_template_loader
  95.             mod = import_module(module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/template/loaders/eggs.py" in <module>
  4.     from pkg_resources import resource_string
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py" in <module>
  2675. add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py" in subscribe
  662.             callback(dist)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py" in <lambda>
  2675. add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py" in activate
  2180.             map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py" in declare_namespace
  1784.             _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py" in _handle_ns
  1755.         loader.load_module(packageName); module.__path__ = path
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pkgutil.py" in load_module
  238.             mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/glumpy-0.1.0-py2.6.egg/glumpy/__init__.py" in <module>
  15. from window import Window, active_window
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/glumpy-0.1.0-py2.6.egg/glumpy/window.py" in <module>
  16. import IPython
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/__init__.py" in <module>
  58.     __import__(name,glob,loc,[])
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/ipstruct.py" in <module>
  17. from IPython.genutils import list2dict2
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/genutils.py" in <module>
  49. from IPython.Itpl import Itpl,itpl,printpl
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/Itpl.py" in <module>
  99.     itpl_encoding = sys.stdin.encoding or 'ascii'

Exception Type: IOError at /
Exception Value: sys.stdin access restricted by mod_wsgi
```

My question is there anyway to enable the eggs template loader but only check through eggs of `INSTALLED_APPS`?  I'd rather not have to switch to virtualenv.  Also these eggs appear in my python path:

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Unidecode-0.04.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pygooglechart-0.3.0-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Graphy-1.0.0-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv-1.5.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/glumpy-0.1.0-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_debug_toolbar-0.8.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Pympler-0.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_profiles-0.2-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_form_utils-0.1.8-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_audit_log-0.2.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_autocomplete-0.3.dev-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Babel-0.9.5-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Genshi-0.6-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Trac-0.12.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/collective.ordereddict-0.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ordereddict-1.1-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_ajax_selects-1.1.4-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/openpyxl-1.2.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_dynamic_choices-0.1.3-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/home/[redacted user name]/django', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/', '/home/[redacted user name]/django/[redacted app name]/', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/IPython/Extensions']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to mod_wsgi 3.3. Don't use mod_wsgi 2.X. Read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/04/wsgi-and-printing-to-standard-output.html

In short, Python code somewhere is trying to use sys.stdin which technically means that code cannot be used portably on all WSGI implementations. Older mod_wsgi versions tried to highlight this to force people to write portable code. Such checks are no longer done in mod_wsgi 3.3 and it allows people to write non portable code.

Comment: I also have the same problem, but the error comes from setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg.